# Uploading a file using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, carrierwave

I am trying to upload a  text file using carrierwave,these are my code files,

```
****class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end
   def create
      @post = Post.create(post_params)

      if @post.save
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
         flash[:notice] = "The post has been uploaded."
      else
         render "index"
      end

   end
   private
      def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:attachment)
   end
end**

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  # attr_accessible :attachment
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :user
end

Routes.rb

resources :posts
    get "users/:id/post" => "posts#index"

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
                *{
                    margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                }
                ul li a{
                  font-size: 1.2em;
                }
                .navbar-brand{
                  font-size:1.5em;
                }
                .bg{
                    background:url("https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/5/005/089/049/38159af.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
                    background-size: cover;
                    height:736px;
                }
                .navbar{
                    margin-bottom: 0px;
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-left:100px;">My Project</a>
              </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active" style="margin-left:100px;"><%= link_to "Home" , :controller => :users, :action => :show %></li>
                <li style="margin-left:100px;"><%= link_to "Post" , :controller => :posts, :action => :index%></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                 <%= link_to logout_path do %>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>&nbsp;Logout
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
            <div class = "alert alert-info">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <%= flash[:notice] %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <div style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:430px;margin-top:50px;width:30%;">
            <%= form_for Post.new, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
                <%= f.file_field :attachment , class: "filestyle"%>
                <%= f.submit "Upload" , class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" ,style:"margin-top:8px;" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>**
```

It is showing an error while running in the localhost,i couldnot able to figure it out how to overcome ,
Here i am attaching the photo of error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9k35.png)

Please help me out.
Here is the error on terminal:

```
**Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"e4yVj+UdBtlfT5OaTb25qRSFy9BpMdoE8Mdgcf1t1IzEw3RPW8+3bxmHJo4RWQH9dFeebzU03iGXKMKvT4aapA==", "post"=>{"attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f34c4b7bb78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170526-15891-18rkkrt.txt>, @original_filename="test.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[attachment]\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}):
    35:             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-left:100px;">My Project</a>
    36:           </div>
    37:           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    38:             <li class="active" style="margin-left:100px;"><%= link_to "Home" , :controller => :users, :action => :show %></li>
    39:             <li style="margin-left:100px;"><%= link_to "Post" , :controller => :posts, :action => :index%></li>
    40:           </ul>
    41:           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

app/views/posts/index.html.erb:38:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__1831786755324942533_69932134090300'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  Rendering /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendering /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendering /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/tej/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (24.9ms)**
```

Rake routes result:

```
 **Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            users#index
             GET    /                            users#index
        new1 GET    /new1(.:format)              users#new1
        new2 GET    /new2(.:format)              users#new2
        new3 GET    /new3(.:format)              users#new3
       users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
             POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
             GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
       login GET    /login(.:format)             sessions#new
             POST   /login(.:format)             sessions#create
      logout GET    /logout(.:format)            sessions#destroy
             DELETE /logout(.:format)            sessions#destroy
    sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          sessions#index
             POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
     session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#show
             PATCH  /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
       posts GET    /posts(.:format)             posts#index
             POST   /posts(.:format)             posts#create
    new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)         posts#new
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)    posts#edit
        post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#show
             PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#update
             PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#update
             DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)         posts#destroy
             GET    /users/:id/post(.:format)    posts#index

Routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root "users#index"
    get '/' => "users#index"
    get "/new1" => "users#new1"
    get "/new2" => "users#new2"
    get "/new3" => "users#new3"
    resources :users
    post "/users" => "users#create"
    get "users/:id" => "users#show"
    get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
    post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
    get '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
    delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :sessions
    resources :posts
    get "users/:id/post" => "posts#index"

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end**
```

Comment: What does that error message say? (Please, no pictures. Just add the error from your terminal to your question.)

Comment: @jvillian please have a look

Comment: See that thing that says `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"})`? That's your hint. Rails is telling you the problem. And it has nothing to do with carrierwave.

Comment: I couldn't able to figure out that why it is coming,the path is present in routes.rb.@jvillian

Comment: Do this: in your terminal, type `rake routes`. Paste those results in your question (nice formatting, please). Also paste the contents of your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: I have uploaded ,please have a look on it @jvillian

Answer (score 0):

You have a `user_path` which you can see right here:

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
```

To link to that, you should do:

```
<%= link_to "Home" , user_path %>
```

instead of :

```
<%= link_to "Home" , :controller => :users, :action => :show %>
```

But, to do that, you need an `@user` variable in your `PostsController create` action. Something like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])

    if @post.save
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
      flash[:notice] = "The post has been uploaded."
    else
      render "index"
    end
  end

  private
    def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:attachment)
  end

end
```

By the way, you should to `Post.new`, not `Post.create`. Otherwise, `if @post.save` is sort of meaningless.

BUUUUUUUT... you don't have `:user_id` in your params:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"e4yVj+UdBtlfT5OaTb25qRSFy9BpMdoE8Mdgcf1t1IzEw3RPW8+3bxmHJo4RWQH9dFeebzU03iGXKMKvT4aapA==", 
  "post"=>{
    "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f34c4b7bb78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170526-15891-18rkkrt.txt>, @original_filename="test.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[attachment]\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n">
  },
  "commit"=>"Upload"
}
```

Sooo, you should add a [`hidden_field`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field) to your new post form so that, when you hit the submit button, the `:user_id` variable shows up in your parameters.

And then everything will be unicorns and rainbows.

Comment: How to add it in form,can you please explain because i am new to it

Comment: I gave you the `hidden_field` link in my answer. If you want help with that, then post a new question that includes: (1) your post form and (2) an explanation of how you're storing your `user_id` (e.g, in session, in cookie, whatever).

Comment: It is giving an error "unknown operator: $oid (2)".

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I don't know what that is. Or where in your code it is arising.

Comment: It is arising when i am trying to get the current user id

Comment: You should post a separate question with the details I specified in my previous comment.

Comment: I can not do that ,because chances of asking question is over, {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>BSON::ObjectId('59270155357afd1443971d01')}}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_project_development.find | FAILED | unknown operator: $oid (2) | 0.000625226s

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (unknown operator: $oid (2)):
    55:   <div style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:430px;margin-top:50px;width:30%;">
    56:    <%= form_for Post.new, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    57:     <%= f.file_field :attachment , class: "filestyle"%>
    58:     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    59:     <%= f.submit "Upload" , class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" ,style:"margin-top:8px;" %>
    60:    <% end %>
    61:   </div>

Comment: Please have a look on both @jvillian

Comment: I don't know anything about MONGODB - and that's the problem you're having. Sorry.

Comment: Its,ok you had helped me a lot to get away from this problem.